# org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped [from User] where User is my bean class

Tags: hibernate, exception, gwt

I am using hibernate with gwt so I want to retrieve data from a table, which I have created a DTO class and a simple java class in which I have initialized DTO object.

In server side I am storing that result in a array list and than using for each loop to storing the query result into User type and than calling a private method by using DTO object.

my code is fine but getting below exception...and while retrieving i am firing "from User" query where User is my simple bean class

this is my hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rs</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="connection.release_mode">auto</property>
        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>

        <!-- MySQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files"></property>

        <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
         <mapping class="com.valto.querybrowser.client.model.User"/>
        <mapping class="com.valto.querybrowser.client.model.UserDTO"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

this is my DTO class UserDTO.java

```
    @Entity(name="usertable")
    @Table(name="usertable")
    public class UserDTO implements Serializable{ 
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -5753020447289277291L;

        @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name="userId")
        private int id;
        @Column(name="user_name")
        private String user_name;

        public UserDTO()
        {

        }
        public UserDTO(int id)
        {
            this.id=id;

        }
        public UserDTO(int id,String user_name)
        {
            this.id=id;
            this.user_name=user_name;

        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getUser_name() {
            return user_name;
        }
        public void setUser_name(String user_name) {
            this.user_name = user_name;
        }


    }
```

this is my simple bean class User.java

```
public class User {

    public int id;
    public String user_name;
    public User(UserDTO udto)
    {
        id=udto.getId();
        user_name=udto.getUser_name();
    }
}
```

and this is my server side code..

```
@Override
    public List<UserDTO> getUsers(String getInput) throws IllegalArgumentException {

        Session session = SessionFacoryCode.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        System.out.println(getInput+"\n");


        try {
            session.beginTransaction();
             List<User> user = new ArrayList<User>(session.createQuery(getInput).list());
                List<UserDTO> userdto = new ArrayList<UserDTO>(user != null ? user.size() : 0);
                if (user != null) {
                  for (User user1 : user) {
                  userdto.add(createUserDTO(user1));
                  }
                }
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            return userdto;


        } catch (Exception e) {
            getInput=null;
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

    }

    private UserDTO createUserDTO(User user1) {

        return new UserDTO(user1.id,user1.user_name);
    }
```

this is my SessionfactoryCode.java

```
public class SessionFacoryCode {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
            try {
                Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure();         
                ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
               . applySettings(cfg.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
                sessionFactory =cfg.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);



            } catch (Throwable th) {
                    System.err.println("Enitial SessionFactory creation failed" + th);
                    throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(th);
            }
    }
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
            return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

this is the error after adding @Entity in User.java...

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.valto.querybrowser.client.model.User
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.determineDefaultAccessType(InheritanceState.java:277)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.getElementsToProcess(InheritanceState.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:665)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3533)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3487)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1376)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1777)
    at com.valto.querybrowser.client.model.SessionFacoryCode.<clinit>(SessionFacoryCode.java:16)
    ... 36 more
[ERROR] 500 - POST /querybrowser/greet (127.0.0.1) 57 bytes
   Request headers
      Host: 127.0.0.1:8888
      Connection: keep-alive
      Content-Length: 145
      X-GWT-Module-Base: http://127.0.0.1:8888/querybrowser/
      X-GWT-Permutation: HostedMode
      Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8888
      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36
      Content-Type: text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=UTF-8
      Accept: */*
      Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8888/QueryBrowser.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
      Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
      Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
   Response headers
      Content-Type: text/plain
   [WARN] Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract java.util.List com.valto.querybrowser.client.GreetingService.gettableNames() throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.valto.querybrowser.client.model.SessionFacoryCode
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:389)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:579)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:265)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:305)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:960)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1021)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.valto.querybrowser.client.model.SessionFacoryCode
    at com.valto.querybrowser.server.GreetingServiceImpl.gettableNames(GreetingServiceImpl.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
    ... 30 more
```

Comment: please post your code for entity and service/dao and hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: where is your user.xml mapping file and its mapping.

Comment: @ankur-singhal, in hibernate.cfg.xml file OP is using `class` attribute instead of `resource` attribute for `mapping` tag. So the OP should use annotations in `User` class instead of hbm.xml mapping file.

Comment: i have mapped that in hibernate.cfg.xml see hibernate.cfg.xml file

Comment: @user3808266 answers have been posted, please have a look

Comment: @user3808266, you do not have any annotations in `User` class so hibernate will not know what to do with that class and throws an exception.

Comment: Chaitanya: i have added annotation in jar after another exception is coming i have posted that also kindly check

Comment: @user3808266, updated my answer, please check. Also I suggest you go through hibernate documentation to understand how hibernate works as the exceptions you mention in your post are very basic issues.

Comment: in your stack-trace it's clearly visible that there is an error to initialize your "SessionFacoryCode"

Answer (score 0):

`User is not mapped [from User]` it means hibernate does not know what the entity `User` is, so include your `User` entity in Hibernate configuration file - `hibernate.cfg.xml` file

For example:

```
<mapping class="mypackage.User"/>
```

Also you are missing `@Entity` declaration for `User` class. So add the annotation `@Entity` for `User` class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="T_USER")
public class User {
...
}
```

Some databases have `USER` as reserved keyword, so try to provide different table name using `@Table` annotation.

**update:**

Now the error says `Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.valto.querybrowser.client.model.User` which indicates you do not have any field in `User` class that represents an identifier, which is mandatory in hibernate. So just add the required annotations for the field `id` in `User` as you did for `UserDTO`, for example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="T_USER")
public class User {
   @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private int id;
   ...
}
```

Comment: Chaitanya: but i dont want to create a User table in database i have created table using UserDTO i want to retireve values from UserDTO now but GWT was giving error that oibject cant be serialized thats why i have used this appoach to retrieve values

Comment: @user3808266, if you want to have only mapping for UserDTO and not for User then you should use UserDTO in createQuery and not the User. Without any mapping for User entity hibernate will not know about User class.

Comment: Chaitnaya i did that but i am using GWT and hibernate together so it was throwing an exception that this type of object cant be serialized

Comment: @user3808266, post the complete stacktrace of the error you are getting in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code is actually causing the problem.

```
List<User> user = new ArrayList<User>(session.createQuery(getInput).list());
```

you are trying to fetch the List from database, and you don not have the table mapped against `User`.

`@Entity` is required to be added for `User.java`.

Comment: now after adding @Entity in User .jaava it is giving another exception.. com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract java.util.List com.valto.querybrowser.client.GreetingService.getUsers(java.lang.String) throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.querybrowser.client.model.SessionFacoryCode

Comment: SessionFactoryCode is my configuration file.. i have added SessionFactoryCode.jaav see up..

Answer (score 0):

User is not mapped [from User] it means hibernate does not know what the entity User is, so include your User entity in Hibernate configuration file - hibernate.cfg.xml file or check you might have done some typo mistake or something.